# Did the profile tags change size?

Tags: support, tagging, tag-wikis, profile-page, questions

I have noticed some changes to the profiles of Math Stack Exchange like not displaying last seen information and how many days you've visited the site (and your current streak). I also really enjoyed the sizes of tags corresponding to the amount used, but it looks like that is now gone:

[image]

These are mine for example. Notice how they are all nice and neat as opposed to the more creative disproportionate tags.

Another change is the questions on the front page of another user not having their related questions, but rather their top network questions which are unrelated to the site. Here is an example of a user’s *Mathematics Stack Exchange* profile front page having unrelated Stack Overflow questions:

[image]

Why did these changes happen? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: FYI if you find any bugs with this please post them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/560258), the answers there have been getting replies fairly consistently, so it’ll probably be fixed.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Yes I saw the bounty, but I am not very active on meta. I still might post, but I have not found any apparent bugs yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is part of some recent network-wide changes to the profile: [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/295232). Some of the reasons for the changes are in other posts on Meta Stack Exchange, e.g. [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/295232).

The top network posts were listed in the previous version of the profile as well, but right under the list of top meta posts; [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507041741/https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228959/glorfindel) is an old snapshot of my profile:

[image]